# Eliminar Archivo o Caperta en C#

Tags: c#

Estoy tratando de eliminar archivo o una capeta completa a traves de C#, pero me sale la siguiente excepción.

> Acceso denegado a la ruta de acceso '03.png'.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
String tempFolder = @"C:\AdjuntosChat\";
if (Directory.Exists(tempFolder))
{
    File.Delete(tempFolder);
    Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.DeleteDirectory(tempFolder, Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.DeleteDirectoryOption.DeleteAllContents);
    foreach (var item in Directory.GetFiles(tempFolder, "*.*"))
    {
        File.Delete(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.DeleteDirectory` debería borrar el directorio con todos sus contenidos. Porque despues intentas borrar los archivos con `File.Delete`?

Comment: Hola, lo intento con esos tres métodos, pero los tres me sale el error que mencione "Acceso denegado a la ruta de acceso '03.png'" 
Le hago un Try Catch y se va a la excepcion al intentar uno de esos metodos. tanto el Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.DeleteDirectory como el File.Delete.

Comment: Entiendo que los archivos que vas a eliminar han sido generados por la misma aplicación? Si ese es el caso, es probable que no hayas liberado los recursos del archivo y por eso no te permita eliminarlo. Puedes probarlo de la siguiente manera: con la aplicación ejecutandose, intenta eliminarles manualmente desde el explorador de windows. Si te da el mismo error, ese es el problema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta añadir esta línea justo antes de eliminar el archivo:

```
File.SetAttributes(item, FileAttributes.Normal);
```

De manera que, según tu código, quede así:

```
foreach (var item in Directory.GetFiles(tempFolder, "*.*"))
{
    File.SetAttributes(item, FileAttributes.Normal);
    File.Delete(item);
}
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias, funciona perfectamente!

Comment: muchas gracias, me funcionó a la primera

Answer (score 0):

Principalmente se debe a dos posibles causas:

1) Falta de permisos suficientes para eliminar el archivo

**Solución:**
Dar permisos sobre el(los) archivo(s) para el usuario que ejecuta tu aplicación, normalmente el permiso de escritura te permite borrar, sin embargo si usas los permisos extendidos de Windows existe un permiso Eliminar.

[Definir, ver, cambiar o quitar permisos de archivos y carpetas](https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/cc754344(v=ws.11).aspx)

Un camino fácil (no el mas recomendado) es otorgar permisos de Control Total sobre toda la carpeta vía código sería algo así:

```
DirectorySecurity sec = Directory.GetAccessControl(path);
// Using this instead of the "Everyone" string means we work on non-English systems.
SecurityIdentifier everyone = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null);
sec.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(everyone, FileSystemRights.Modify | FileSystemRights.Synchronize, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Allow));
Directory.SetAccessControl(path, sec);
```

fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298905/add-everyone-privilege-to-folder-using-c-net

2) El archivo se encuentra en uso por otro proceso:

**Solución**:

Asegúrate que no sea tu mismo programa quien tiene "agarrado" el archivo en alguna otra rutina: usando variables por método, no globales, ni por procedimientos, cerrar streams de acceso a archivos, etc.

En caso de no ser así puedes ver que proceso tiene "agarrado" el archivo con Process Explorer de Sysinternals, siguiendo los pasos de esta página:

[Como borrar, mover o renombrar archivos bloqueados por Windows](http://geek.pe/como-borrar-mover-o-renombrar-archivos-bloqueados-por-windows/)

Si bien Process Explorer te permite liberar el archivo, te recomiendo enfocarte en encontrar el por qué se encuentra bloqueado para que el bloqueo no se repita ya liberada tu aplicación. El antivirus puede ser una causa.